# Why won't my Linux install boot?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

It's my first time compiling a Linux kernel. Everything went well until I hit this problem. After I edit my `/etc/fstab`:

[image: /etc/fstab screenshot]

and edit `etc/lilo.conf`:

[image: /etc/lilo.conf screenshot]

I want to set the info about crux in `lilo`, so I run `lilo` and the system prompt:

[image: lilo screenshot]

Then I run:

```
modprobe dm-mode
```

Things seem fine, but when I reboot the OS I get:

[image: boot screenshot]

I have no idea how to fix the problem; the next time I use the ISO to reboot, I get the same problem:

[image: boot screenshot]

**Update**

I set the root read-write in the `lilo.conf`, it seems that I can login, but the system still prompts that the `/` item is not found in the `fstab`. But I have already set it. And here is the prompt:

[image]

And what's more, when I reboot it, I can already login to the OS, but it still prompts the same error. And, when I open the `/etc/fstab`, I can find the `/` item in it. So, I wonder if I should notice the system about the change in the `/etc/fstab` -- but after long time searching the Internet, I found nothing about it.

Comment: Why did you mount your root read-only?

Comment: read-only is just default set

Comment: i donn't know yet,maybe i choose some unrelated tags,but someone can help me about this problem yet?

Comment: i set the root read-write in the lilo.conf,it seems that i can login,but the system stiil prompt that the / item is not found in the fstab.But,anyway,i have set it before.someone can give me a hand?!

Comment: Can you take another screenshot of the error message about `/` not in `fstab`?

Comment: i have aready post the screenshot in the answe section^

Comment: Do you have several disks on your system? If you have a file `/boot/map`, what does it contain?

Comment: well,guys.i have aready found the answer to the error.please take a look about my second answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think I fixed it. I noticed when editing `/etc/fstab` in vim that one of the lines was red. I'm not very familiar with vim, but I think it was indicating some kind of mistake, so I rewrote the line:

[image: vim screenshot]

Now when I boot it works:

[image: Screenshot of a successful boot]

Comment: Do yourself a favor and switch to grub2; lilo is woefully outdated and hasn't seen a stable release in nearly 4 years.  Even grub-legacy (grub-0.97) is better than lilo.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly over my head, but I noticed one small thing not related to your immediate problem.

/boot (on its own partition) is normally created as ext2 - not ext3 because it does not require any journaling - it's almost completely static and because it needs a tiny amount of disk space (somewhere around 100MB IIRC).  The minimum size for an ext3 partition is larger than /boot needs and ext2 will do it.   All that /boot normally holds is your kernel image and boot loader files like those needed by grub and probably lilo.

Changing this will free up a tiny amount of disk space for another partition to use, but shouldn't otherwise affect anything.

Some people recommend making /boot as large as 500MB, but that's probably overkill.  YMMV.

Comment: Good advice on `ext2` for `/boot` -- and 500 megs does seem a bit big, I've got nine currently installed kernels and 175 megs used. (Time to prune, I guess.)